# Logic question: [p --> (q v r)] iff [(p ∧ ~q) --> r]

Tags: logic

I don't understand the following if and only if. I have trouble with why it is "only if".
$$[p \Rightarrow (q \lor r)]  \iff [(p \land \lnot q) \Rightarrow r]$$

**Left side of iff says**: If p is true, then either q or r is true.

**Right side of iff says**: If p is true and not q is true, then r must be true.

But, the right side can also be re-written as $[(p \wedge \lnot r) \Rightarrow q]$. Obviously, it's still true!

**The confusion**: Since

$$[p \Rightarrow (q \lor r)]  \iff [(p \land \lnot q) \Rightarrow r]$$
$$[p \Rightarrow (q \lor r)]  \iff [(p \land \lnot r) \Rightarrow q]$$

both are true, it's not an iff. "Only if" means we can have only one if (necessary and sufficient), not two if's. Here, two different if's on the right can be written.

Why? Is it because on the left $(p \lor q)$ is the same as $(q \lor p)$, so it's trivial?

Comment: The RHS can not be rewritten as $p\vee\neg r\implies q$

Comment: Why not? What if I did switch position between q and r on the left? Write: $[p \Rightarrow (r \lor q)]  \iff [(p \land \lnot r) \Rightarrow q]$.

Comment: You can rewrite it as $p\wedge\neg r\implies q$, that is correct. But not as $p\vee\neg r\implies q$. I have made the edit for you.

Comment: So, it's a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have got $(1)\iff(2)$ and $(1)\iff(3)$. This doesn't lead to any contradiction but implies that $(2)\iff(3)$. In fact $p\wedge\neg r\implies q$ is equivalent to $p\wedge\neg q\implies r$.

To see this just recall that $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $\neg A\vee B$. So both $p\wedge\neg r\implies q$ and $p\wedge\neg q\implies r$ are equivalent to $\neg p\vee r\vee q$. You can use the same technique to prove the original equivalence.

Comment: Typo, fixed. Thanks!

Comment: How is the RHS is 0 if it is $0 \rightarrow \text{something}$  which is always true?

Comment: @WATER The OP changed the question after I pointed out the typo

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x\implies y)$ is the same as $(\lnot x\lor y)$, using this, the result is almost immediate:

- $(p\implies (q\lor r))=(\lnot p\lor(q\lor r))=(\lnot p\lor q\lor r)$
- $((p\land\lnot q)\implies r)=(\lnot (p\land\lnot q)\lor r)=(\lnot p\lor\lnot\lnot q)\lor r=(\lnot p\lor q\lor r)$

Comment: Is there a simpler way to read through and understand this besides flipping symbols? Like reason it out with a concrete example? Like "If it rains, I either stay home or call a Uber."

Comment: Yes, for instance take a binary situation. p="being  a child", q="being a boy", r="being a girl". The first one is simply (child $\implies$ boy or girl) while the second is (child not a boy$\implies$ girl).

Comment: I don't understand this example: "If $xy=0$, then $x=0$ or $y=0$", which means "If $xy=0$ and $x \ne 0$, then $y=0$". But, it doesn't say if $x$ can ever be $0$, when $y\ne0$ (i.e. $x=0$, then $y\ne 0$). Or in fact, if $x$ can ever be $0$ at all, regardless of $y$.

Comment: Let me answer my example: $x$ has to be 0 or not 0. It has to be either true or false. You can't say what if it's always false, never true. Logic table assumes a variable can take on either true or false value.